# How can I get the Tomcat JSESSIONID on the client side?

Tags: html, tomcat, gwt

I want to get the JSESSIONID of Tomcat on the client side. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: This is the 2nd time that you asked a question which in real world should never be practiced. Honestly said, this all smells. What is it, the problem for which you think that getting the `HttpSession` associated with JSESSONID in server side and getting the JSESSIONID value in client side is "the" solution? Elaborate about this in a new question, you'll get answers how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depend on how is the JSESSIONID transmitted:

- if it's as a session cookie, see how to [obtain cookies with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- if it is in the URL, you can parse the `document.location`

However I don't see much of a reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a **ajax** call to your server code like **Spring controller** or **Servlets** and get the response string as JSESSIONID and then store it in the **javascript**, only after your **DOM** is fully loaded  .