# SessionInformation expiration doesn't lead to user log out from system

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, logout

I want to have ability to force log out another user if admin want to block it.

I have read following answer

[How do you log out all logged in users in spring-security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751964/how-do-you-log-out-all-logged-in-users-in-spring-security)

I have wrote following code:

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
...
private void logout(String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
        User user = (User) principal;
        if (user.getUsername().equals(name)) {
            sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false).stream()
                    .forEach(i -> i.expireNow());
        }
    }
}
```

I open 2 browsers for (1-admin and 2-user)

I login both.

admin clicks to block user

in debug I get into

```
if (user.getUsername().equals(name)) {
```

And see following state:
[image]

But after this code execution user still log in in system and can scroll site.

If repeat this operation `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false)`will returns empty list.

Spring-security configuration:

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <http auto-config="true" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/loginAdmin" login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin"
                    default-target-url="/admin"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginAdminFailed"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="authAdminSuccessHandler"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/accounts/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/money/**" access="ROLE_FINANSIER, ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/pictures"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/statistic/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/rules/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/addImageToTerminal"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/deleteTerminalImage"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/systemGroupsModeration" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/adminUsers" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/contentModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/campaignModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/monitoring" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/loginAdmin"/>
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
        </port-mappings>
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/invalid-session" />
    </http>    

    <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.impl.UserSecurityService"/>
    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.RoleAuthSuccessHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="authAdminSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.admin.RoleAuthAdminHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="adminSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.admin.impl.TerminalAdminSecurityServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="webexpressionHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

    <authentication-manager id="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="internalUserAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="noopEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="noopEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"/>
    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can scroll the site? What if you refresh the page?

Comment: That session used in the `SessionRegistry` is not the `HttpSession` those are different things.

Comment: @Predrag Maric after refreshing page user still logged in

Comment: @M. Deinum I understand it but I have read this advise here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751964/how-do-you-log-out-all-logged-in-users-in-spring-security

Comment: That does nothing for the session in the `SessionRegistry` that is for detecting `HttpSession` creation and destruction. Which is different from the `Session` used by the `SessionRegistry`.

Comment: Thus should I create own SessionListener and create map<session,sessionId> and inside **logout** method explicitly invalidate session?

Comment: @M. Deinum maybe you can advise something nicer?

Comment: How can I get session if I know sessionId ?

Comment: doc http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionInformation.html   An "expired" session is removed as soon as possible by a Filter.

Comment: You cannot get the `HttpSession` from another session/request as that would be a bit of a security breach :). But do you have that filter registered? Without seeing your configuration that is hard to tell.

Comment: @M. Deinum I added configuration to my topic

Comment: **But do you have that filter registered?** What the filter and how can I register filter?

Comment: You have 2 http configuration blocks. Only your admin has concurreny configured. So trying to disable a user shouldn't really do much...

Comment: @M. Deinum I want to have ability for admin can block another admin thus it is normally

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This working:

spring security configuration:

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/loginAdmin" login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin"
                    default-target-url="/admin"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginAdminFailed"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="authAdminSuccessHandler"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/accounts/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/money/**" access="ROLE_FINANSIER, ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/pictures"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/statistic/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/rules/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/addImageToTerminal"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/deleteTerminalImage"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/systemGroupsModeration" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/adminUsers" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/contentModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/campaignModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/monitoring" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/loginAdmin"/>
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
        </port-mappings>
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/" />
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.impl.UserSecurityService"/>
    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.RoleAuthSuccessHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="authAdminSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.admin.RoleAuthAdminHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="adminSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.admin.impl.TerminalAdminSecurityServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="webexpressionHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

    <authentication-manager id="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="internalUserAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="noopEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="noopEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"/>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Inside `logout` method we set information that session is expired inside sessionRegistry and `concurrencyFilter` read this and expire http session.

Also I added

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>

</listener>
```

to web.xml