# Create a map of all active session?

Tags: java, session, sessionid

i want to get a map of all active session in my application.
i am using struts and tomcat.

or

how i create a map of only active session for my application with session id as key and session object as value.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i load Java HttpSession from JSESSIONID?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092495/1225328)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should definitely go for `HttpSessionListener` to implement. This will help you capture the session creation and destroy events. That's where you can write the logic to add and remove the session objects from map accordingly.

For example

```
 @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    //get the session object from the event
    //put the session id and session object to your map
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    //get the session object
    //remove it from the map using it's session id
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing exactly that in TOMCAT. At least not a portable solution. I guess you could search the stored sessions on the filesystem if that's the manner you are storing sessions (it's up to your Tomcat's configuration).

An alternative would be registering a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and counting and storing them your self.