# Glassfish 3.X, programmatically handle the termination of arbitrary HTTPSession

Tags: java, jsf, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Consider the following scenario.

I've a Java EE web application (JSF 2.2, JPA, EJB 3.0 even if the framework doesn't matter here) deployed on Glassfish 3.1.1 with a login protected area, which I'm protecting through the standard Glassfish security mechanisms.

My business model is based on selling access to this web application as a service, forbidding multiple logins at the same time for a single username/password. For this reason I'm keeping a column in my database that I increment upon user login and I decrement upon user logout. Additionally, I've a method in a SessionScoped managed bean annotated with @PreDestroy that takes care of decrementing the counter when the session expires (60 minutes configured in the web.xml via the session-timeout attribute).

When the user try to login with a counter greater than 1, the application notifies him about the issue, inviting him to logut the previous workstation first.

This is working quite well, but we are having an incrementing amount of users that perform their actions, close the browser (without loggin out), and then try to authenticate from a different workstation within the session timeout limit (which, again, we've set to 60 min).

In these cases we would like to be able to **offer the opportunity of closing all the previous sessions associated to the user login directly from the new workstation** (so an user X, logged with his own session, should be able to ask the termination of different sessions logically linked to its account). I'm aware that if he/she just waits 60 min the session will be eventually terminated by Glassfish but we would like to avoid the support requests coming from this "issue" (you know it's hard to explain this kind of stuff to non-technical users).

My first plan would be to store the jsession ID of the user HTTPSession somewhere, to access the old sessions (if any) via the stored jsession ID and to close or invalidate them on demand. I've read a lot of material on the subject, and I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092363/how-can-i-load-java-httpsession-from-jsessionid/) with apparently the answer I'm looking for (a method of storing the HTTPSession in a map using the jsessionID as key to get them back). It seems pretty simple and I could implement that in a matter of minutes, BUT the comments below, especially the second part of the answer coming from @BalusC is driving me to ask your opinion on how I should implement this in a safe way.

It's a matter of best practice, how would you guys implement this?

I don't need code, just your opinion as Java EE architects or a reference of some sort of documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of all logins in DB (you can use `HttpSessionListener` to remove entry when session get destroyed). Make sure that you've a boolean column "should kill session now!" in DB which defaults to false. When the action is given to kill all other sessions now, set the boolean to `true` for those sessions. In a filter, on every request, check the boolean value in DB and handle accordingly.

This way you don't need to have a handle of all physical `HttpSession` instances.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. Instead of destroying all the older sessions you're suggesting to logically invalidate them allowing access to the new one. This seems OK even if I have some concerns about the additional overhead introduced by the filter acting on every single request. I accept your answer and I'll let you know if it works as expected.