# Best way for long-time login with Java Servlets

Tags: java, http, session, servlets

In my web appication i need to recognize signed in users even if they restart the browser ("Remember me" function of web sites). What is the best practice to achieve this using Java Servlet API?

I've considered the following options:

1. Using long-term HttpSession sessions and storing user identifier as an attribute of the session. This approach doesn't permit user to restart browser, because JSESSIONID cookie is not persistent and there is no standard way to change its properties. The only option i consider is to use SessionCookieConfig interface of Tomcat 7.0 to tune default JSESSIONID parameters. But there are doubts about the scalability of such solution, because Tomcat will store all sessions for a long period of time.
2. Using short-term HttpSessions together with some persistent cookie which stores the user identifier with some security hash. When user restarts the browser, it sends persistent cookie and application server binds new session with user identifier.

What is the common way to achieve this?

Comment: Just copy what the big guys are doing like Google, Yahoo or Microsoft...

Comment: What approach do they use? Can you suggest where to get more information?

Comment: Duplicate of [Java - How do I keep a user logged into my site for months?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185951/java-how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-my-site-for-months)

Comment: @BalusC Yes, it seems to be the similar question and you gave useful answer. However we have slightly different key points here: it is still interesting if we can use common Java facilities such as HttpSesstion API?

Comment: @BalusC BTW, in the comments of the question you pointed out, there is a discussion concerning two different approaches: using some DB to check cookie validity and using some hash of user information in the cookie itself. What are pros.& cons. of these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I have always needed more control over my sessions, because I need them to work across multiple web applications, so I implemented my own solution from scratch.  It is pretty easy, just hash a random number and store it in a database.  If you don't have or want a RDBMS just some sort of key/value store.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using normal filter-based authentication?  How secure does your site need to be?

One way:

Drop a cookie with a code in it on their browser.  In Tomcat, have a typical filter configured.  The filter grabs the code and checks it against the database for validity. If the code is valid the normal Tomcat authentication is avoided.  If there needs to be any persisted session variables, you can load them from the database now.

Drop a new cookie code with every response. It should include a hash of a salt, the user's ID, and the user's IP address.  That way the cookie will do no good if the request comes from the wrong computer.  Though IPs are spoofable.

Bear in mind, you're short-circuiting security when you do this.  You're saying, "Oh look, you've just come out of nowhere. I think I know you! Here, have the keys to my castle!" This sounds like the sort of request we'd get from the marketing folks who didn't understand a thing about security and didn't care since it wasn't there problem if we got hacked.