# Cookies for "Remember me" in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, cookies

I have a login page, and I want to add the "Remember me" feature; so that if user logs out and opens the page again, his username and password are loaded.
For this, when user logs in (and "remember me" is checked") I save the following cookies:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("vtusername", username);
userCookie.setMaxAge(3600);
((HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext()
       .getResponse()).addCookie(userCookie);
Cookie passCokie = new Cookie("vtpassword", password);
passCokie.setMaxAge(3600);
 ((HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext()
       .getResponse()).addCookie(passCokie);
```

The problem is that later (in the same session) I read the cookies and I see that maxAge = -1; even though I'm setting it to 3600... why is that?
Another issue: if I set the cookie secure with userCookie.setSecure(true) then I can't read it (it dissapears).

Another question: since a password is being stored in a cookie, should I encrypt it some how? what is the best practice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but saving the password (in whatever format) in the cookie is a bad idea. Any one can tamper it. Consider storing the sessionid or some id unique to the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *The problem is that later (in the same session) I read the cookies and I see that maxAge = -1; even though I'm setting it to 3600... why is that?*

Because the browser doesn't send the maxage back. It only sends the cookie name=value back. The maxage is only stored in the browser. You can check it in the cookie viewer/editor of the webbrowser itself. In Firefox for example, you can check all cookies by *Tools > Options > Privacy > Remove individual cookies*. Enter the domain (e.g. localhost) to see the cookies.

> *Another issue: if I set the cookie secure with userCookie.setSecure(true) then I can't read it (it dissapears).*

It only works when the request/response is served over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Also, when the request is already served over HTTPS, it will already default to secure=true.

> *Another question: since a password is being stored in a cookie, should I encrypt it some how? what is the best practice?*

Do not store the raw name/password in two cookies. Apart from that this can easily go in just a single cookie, this is a very bad idea and easily hackable. Use a single cookie with an autogenerated long, unique and impossible-to-guess value. Store this value along with the user ID in a database in the server side. When someone visits your site with this cookie, but the user is not logged in yet (i.e. there's no `User` object in session), then you can do the automatic login.

#### See also:

- [How to implement "Stay logged in"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-applic)
- [How to keep a user logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185951/java-how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-my-site-for-months)

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate your fast answer. I was not using data base; instead I'm using WS calls (the application server handles part of the logic and persistence). I gues I'll have to set up a small data base in order to provide "remember me" feature..

Comment: You're welcome. As an alternative you can also encrypt the username/password with a strong encryption algorithm (RSA? DES?) and store the (hex)encoded value as cookie value.