# How Remember Me works with Restful Web Service

Tags: java, security, jax-ws

I am working in **Java,Restful Web Services** at Server side and **Jsp,javascript** at Client side

I want to know how `Remember me` works

I have doing analysis so many sites and i am getting one thing is that they dont use Cookie for this purpose.

Comment: What makes you think they don't use cookies? There is no other way that a website would be aware of who you are without login.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Me works with Cookies. You dont need to use `REST` for this.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836520/295264) answer from Balcus to see how.

Comment: you mean my UserNAme and Password is filled out in form by Cookies ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati, Yeah.... not the password, but they generally store a token which validates the login session, but UserName are almost filled out by cookies.

Comment: try Facebook by Removing Cookie facebook fills all detail if remember checked, i want to create this type of mechanism for my site.