# Automatic login to JSF application on revisits, after once logged in

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, primefaces

For typical most typical internet facing websites when you login & leave the website by just closing the tab (*without logging out*), then on successive revisits, you may not be required to re-specify your credentials or login, you are directly logged in.

How does all that happen on the backend? How can I enable such mechanism on my JSF 2.1 application?

---

Using JSF 2.1 on Tomcat7 server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basically done by a long-living cookie. This functionality is not provided by the JSF API as it's just a simple component based MVC framework. This functionality is also not provided by the standard Java EE API. Some authenticaiton frameworks like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) and [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) offer this functionality.

If you need to implement this using "plain" Java EE / JSF, then you'd need to create a long-living cookie yourself during login by [`ExternalContext#addResponseCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#addResponseCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29). The cookie value must be a long, unique, autogenerated and hard-to-guess value (e.g. [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) which you also store in the DB associated with the user ID. Then, you can use a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) to check for the cookie by [`HttpServletRequest#getCookies()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29) when the logged-in user has been confirmed to be absent. If the cookie is found and is valid, then auto-login the user.

To improve security, provide if necessary the enduser the option to "lock" this cookie on the user IP which you also store in the DB along with the cookie ID and user ID.

#### See also:

- [How to implement "Stay Logged In" when user login in to the web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli)
- [How do I keep a user logged into my site for months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185951/java-how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-my-site-for-months)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Security or Apache Shiro, both of them support this with the proper filter. On the backend Spring Security works by having a persistent store of remember me tokens, and Shiro I think signs a hash value.

Here's the spring guide: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Here's the shiro guide: http://shiro.apache.org/java-authentication-guide.html

If you're using Java EE Security (please tell me it ain't so), you're limited to what your container can support, unless you want to design a customer login filter. An customer filter could sign a cookie with a MAC code and validate it against a database. I don't believe tomcat 7 has this built in, you'd probably need to check out GlassFish (which supports SSO, I don't think it supports remember me).

Comment: I haven't been using SS or shiro.. the app is deployed on tomcat container

Comment: >`If you're using Java EE Security you're limited to what your container can support, unless you want to design a customer login filter.` - Or a custom JASPIC auth module of course ;) That's the Java EE standard for it.