# How to "automatically login" user after remember me cookie is checked?

Tags: jsf, authentication, remember-me

I need to implement "Remember me" functionallity on my JSF site, i´ve been researching about this topic trying to find what the best practices are. Ive found many answers, but i still have a question based on the technology i use and the way i store user passwords in my database.

**Summarizing what i've found**

- Create a database table containing the user and a hard to guess long serial.
- When a user logs in with the remember me option checked, generate a registry on the db table and send a cookie to the user with both username and serial in it.
- In case the same user isnt logged in, and has a valid cookie according to the database, **Automatically login** the user.

**How i actually login users**

Based on Java EE standards i use JAAS and i store the MD5 version of user passwords.
I login my users through the login method of the HttpServletRequest class which needs a **username and a password** in order to validate the authentication and set the user principal.

---

Based on these two facts, how can i do the automatic login based on this best practice if i need both username and password in order to login the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how can i do the automatic login based on this best practice if i need both username and password in order to login the user?*

Just get username and password straight from the DB based on the value of the "remember me" cookie. Then you can provide them to the `HttpServletRequest#login()` method.

Note that the value of the "remember me" cookie should absolutely not contain any hints about the username, password nor ID. It should be an absolutely random value. The `java.util.UUID` is helpful here.

#### See also:

- [Automatic login to JSF application on revisits, after once logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810224/automatic-login-to-jsf-application-on-revisits-after-once-logged-in)

Comment: Hello @BalusC, thank you for your answer, im not sure if you took in account that all i have in my database is the MD5 version of the user passwords.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: thats a problem because the login method of the HttpServletRequest requires both a username and a password (the password must be the authentic user password in order to be automatically hashed and compared to the MD5 version in the database)

Comment: I actually have MD5 as password hashing in my realm, should i disable it at the realm level and do it myself?

Comment: Oh, this way. Yes, let the code or DB hash it instead of the realm itself.